# Java Swing create Oval by Click

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

i thought it would be easy to create a little programm with java :

- i create a jFrame => (size 500,500 and it is visible)
- i add a mouseListener to the jFrame
- when i click i want to create a oval at this position

so what i have done:

- i created a class circle ( JPanel)
- everytime the mouslistener notices that i clicked on the jFrame, I add a new circle to it. (it gets the x and y points as parameter)

then something shocking happened:
i clicked into my jFrame... nothing happened. 
i thought : ok let's make a repaint after creating the new circle... but it happened nothing!
only if i click on the windwos Border and restretch it it "repaints" it.

what also ist really bad and sad, at the same time, is that if i click at a position and then at another position , and then restretch the frame, it only paints the last circle :( it should paint both! )

now i put repaint() on thousand different places but there was no difference. I also tried something with setopaque etc. just because i didnt know what to do at this point!

**Here the mouseListener:** you can ignore the color

```
public class Aufgabe3 {
    public static Circ.CircleColor actualColor = CircleColor.ROT;

    // fromone color to another depend on the actual
    public static Circ.CircleColor getNextColor(Circ.CircleColor aktuell) {
        switch (aktuell) {
        case ROT:
            return Circ.CircleColor.GRÜN;
        case GRÜN:
            return Circ.CircleColor.GELB;
        case GELB:
            return Circ.CircleColor.ROT;
        default:
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(jFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // jFrame.add()
        // farbenfolge rot,grün,gelb--
        jFrame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("clicked");
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                System.out.println("coords:" + x + "|" + y);
                Circ circ = new Circ(x, y, actualColor);
                circ.repaint();
                jFrame.add(circ);
                jFrame.repaint();
                System.out.println(actualColor);
                // actualisation of the next color
                actualColor = getNextColor(actualColor);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**and now the circle :**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Circ extends JComponent {
    static public enum CircleColor {
        ROT, GRÜN, GELB
    };

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private CircleColor circleColor;

    public Circ() {
        super();

    }

    public Circ(int x, int y, CircleColor circColor) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.circleColor = circColor;
        System.out.println("new circle created");
        setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        setVisible(true);
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    public Color decodeCircleColor(CircleColor farbe) {
        switch (farbe) {
        case GRÜN:
            return Color.GREEN;
        case GELB:
            return Color.yellow;
        case ROT:
            return Color.red;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("paint");
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);
        g2d.setColor(decodeCircleColor(circleColor));
        // g2d.drawOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for a step-by-step example on how to do custom painting.

Answer (score 1):

The default layout of a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`.
When adding components to a `BorderLayout` without specifying a position, they are added to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` replacing the previous one set to this position.
That means that you always have only one `Circle` added to your JFrame.

In any case, it looks like you're trying to draw circles at the cursor's position which means that you'll have to add the `Circle` components to the `JFrame` at different positions which is not that easy.
Instead of that, you're better off adding just one component to the frame and drawing all the circles in that component.

Comment: hmm i will try ! i will add a JPanel to the JFrame and then draw on the JPanel :D let's see! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your component in a `mouseClicked` event, that's probably revalidate that you should call because you change the container (the `JFrame`). Also, JFrame are special: they have a *content pane* and you should add component this way:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(...);
```

The default content pane use a `BorderLayout`.

Adding a component for each click is probably overkill and you'll have problem with layout unless you set it to `null` (eg: the absolute layout) and call setBounds(x, y, 50, 50) for each circle.

However, since you overrides `paintComponent` you may directly draw the ovals and not care about layout or components.

Add the `Circle` component once, with a BorderLayout.CENTER constraints. This will ensure your `Circle` will get the max size it can.

The `MouseListener` should be on the Circle and you'll have to make it focusable (`setFocus(true)`).

Each time the mouse is clicked on the `Circle`, register the mouse position in a list (eg: `List<Point>`) and then call repaint:

```
circle.points.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()); // 
circle.repaint();
```

Each time `paintComponent(Graphics)` is called, use the list to draw the ovals in the order their were called.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    System.out.println("paint");
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(g2d);
    g2d.setColor(decodeCircleColor(circleColor));
    // if you know lambda
    points.forEach(p -> g2d.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 50, 50)); 
    // or if you don't know lambda yet.
    // for (Point p : points) g2d.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 50, 50)); 
}
```

Note that you may use a Point or any relevant class (for example, you may use a concrete object which would store a `Paint` object such as `java.awt.Color` to change the oval' color).